# Need to add a a header when returning an asset using the Play Framework Assets Controller

Tags: java, playframework

I need to return pdf files with the header

```
X-Robots-Tag: noindex
```

https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_meta_tag?hl=de#robots-meta-tag-verwenden

Is there a way to do this using the standard play Assets Controller? Took a look inside the source code and the only thing that seems to be configurable is:

```
val configuredCacheControl = config(_.getString("\"assets.cache." + name + "\""))
```

Thanks

Comment: thanks for the editing

Comment: Which version of Play?

Comment: You could always write your own assets controller and add the header you want in the action method.

Comment: Anyway, I think you can easily do what you want using a filter: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaHttpFilters#A-simple-logging-filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might go with [Kris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1278769/kris)'s idea. Something kinda like this should get you part of the way there, basically all I'm doing is leveraging the Play! Controller that serves static resources but adding a header to the result:

```
object AssetsController extends Controller {

def modifiedAsset(path: String, file: String): Future[Result] = Async.action { implicit request =>
  Assets.at(path, file)(request).map { result => 
   result.withHeaders(("X-Robots-Tag", "noindex"))
  }
}
```

Then your `routes` file would need to be modified from `controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)` to `controllers.AssetsController.modifiedAsset(path="/public", file)`

Comment: thanks for the reply, I solved the problem using the controller