# How to resolve "The Content-Type HTTP header is missing charset attribute" in play application?

Tags: nginx, networking, utf-8, playframework, nginx-config

We had a security check on our application, and it reported a few issues like missing charset attribute for `.css` and `.js` files.

```
Attack Type: Undefined charset attribute
Error Description: The Content-Type HTTP header is missing charset attribute
Content-Type: text/CSS
```

I found this answer [The Content-Type HTTP header is missing charset attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53077535/the-content-type-http-header-is-missing-charset-attribute)

Our application has been developed using play framework and I tried to add in the `application.conf` like this

```
AddDefaultCharset : utf-8
AddCharset utf-8 = [.htm .html .js .css]
```

But it didn't work. How can I resolve this issue in our application?

Thanks

Comment: Is your application header `HTML` has `<meta charset="utf-8">` at header?

Comment: Make sure your `CSS link` has `rel="stylesheet"` and `JS script ` has `type="text/javascript"`

Comment: @Rex, it is already there. You can see the problem in given StackOverflow link. I have the exact same problem in play application. You can refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53077535/the-content-type-http-header-is-missing-charset-attribute

Comment: Sorry I had no Idea. I tested new Play application but no problem. Try to remove your `CSS ` and `JS` that has problem and use other if the problem still exists.

Comment: You need to extend assets handler to your own and add the header you want. Like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36942470/need-to-add-a-a-header-when-returning-an-asset-using-the-play-framework-assets-c

Comment: @Rex it does not show the problem in local but when you deploy it and then inspect your website you will see this issue.

Comment: Did you try the suggested answer from the link you've added?

Comment: @AndriyKuba umm okay will see if there will be no option. Right now I am trying to do if I could set some configurations to resolve this. Thanks

Comment: @Rex yes I have mentioned it that I have tried but it didn't work. Since we use Nginx web server so I am trying to know how can I set these files in nginx.conf.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe You can try this one.

`application.conf`

```
play.filters.enabled += "play.filters.headers.SecurityHeadersFilter"
```

change this one, as Play Docs instructed.

```
play.filters.headers.contentTypeOptions - 
sets X-Content-Type-Options, “nosniff” by default.
```

[Source here.](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/SecurityHeaders)

Comment: I read the source doc but will it ensure that charset would be utf-8?